# How to use the IN keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `PropertyFeatures` which has three columns. The first one - `PropertyFeatureId` is an auto incremented column, the second one - `Propertyid` is a foreign key of the `Property` table, and the last one - `Featureid` is a foreign key of the `Feature` table.

```
+------------------------------------------+
| PropertyFeatureId  PropertyId  FeatureId |
+------------------------------------------+
| 1                   1             1      |
| 2                   1             2      |
| 3                   2             2      |
| 4                   2             3      |
| 5                   2             4      |
+------------------------------------------+

SELECT propertyFeatures.PropertyId       
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] IN (1,2)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
```

The above query gives the following result:

```
PropertyId 
1
2
```

But **I want to get the following** result:

```
PropertyId
1
```

because `Featureid` 1 and 2 are available only for `PropertyId` 1.

If I change the query to the following:

```
SELECT propertyFeatures.PropertyId       
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures .[FeatureId] IN (2,3,4)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
```

It will only display:

```
PropertyId 
2
```

because `Featureid`  2, 3 and 4 are available only for `PropertyId` 2.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: Looking at what you have posted, Featureid 1 and 2 exist for Propertyid 1 and Featureid 2 is there for Propertyid 2 so the query should be OK, it's the data you might want to look into.

Comment: i want the result like fololws,if i give featureid 1 ,it display the properties which has featureid 1.And if i give featureid 1 and 2 it will show the only the properties which has featureid 1 and 2.But it show either the property has featureid 1  OR 2

Comment: Was any of the answers helpful @Ganesh? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that `WHERE a IN (1, 2)` is actually a shortcut for `WHERE a = 1 OR a = 2`. This will not give you the intersection of the two sets, only the combination of the set where the first filter is valid with the set where the second filter is valid. In your case, a check with `EXISTS` might be what you are searching for - or `INTERSECT`.

Example with `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT   propertyFeatures.PropertyId       
FROM     PropertyFeatures AS propertyFeatures
INNER JOIN Feature AS feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE    propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] = 1
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
INTERSECT
SELECT   propertyFeatures.PropertyId       
FROM     PropertyFeatures AS propertyFeatures
INNER JOIN Feature AS feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE    propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] = 2
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId;
```

Example with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT   propertyFeatures.PropertyId       
FROM     PropertyFeatures AS propertyFeatures
INNER JOIN Feature AS feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE    EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PropertyFeatures AS P
                 INNER JOIN Feature AS F ON F.id = P.FeatureId
                 WHERE P.FeatureId = 1)
         AND
         EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PropertyFeatures AS P
                 INNER JOIN Feature AS F ON F.id = P.FeatureId
                 WHERE P.FeatureId = 2);
```

(Code not tested, so please check for yourself if it works!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT propertyFeatures.PropertyId, 
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures 
INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures .[FeatureId] IN (1,2)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN propertyFeatures .[FeatureId] IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `EXISTS` clause instead of an `IN` caluse:

### [Demo Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/29304/5)

**Create Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE PropertyFeatures
    ([PropertyFeatureId] int, [PropertyId] int, [FeatureId] int)
;

INSERT INTO PropertyFeatures
    ([PropertyFeatureId], [PropertyId], [FeatureId])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 1, 2),
    (3, 2, 2),
    (4, 2, 3),
    (5, 2, 4)
;
```

**SQL Statement:**

```
select distinct PropertyId
from   PropertyFeatures pf1 
where  exists (select PropertyId 
               from PropertyFeatures pf2 
               where FeatureID = 1 and pf1.PropertyId = pf2.PropertyId)
   and exists (select PropertyId 
               from PropertyFeatures pf2 
               where FeatureID = 2 and pf1.PropertyId = pf2.PropertyId)
```

So each subquery within the `exists` statement returns a `PropertyId` and you can `and` them both together.

The issue I can see with this is that you would have to add another `EXISTS` clause each time you wanted to query more `FeatureId` values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check with this for feature id has 1,2:

```
SELECT count(propertyFeatures.PropertyId) as cnt, propertyFeatures.PropertyId    
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures 
INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] IN (1,2)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
having COUNT(1)>1
```

For 2,3,4:

```
SELECT count(propertyFeatures.PropertyId)as cnt, propertyFeatures.PropertyId    
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures 
INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] IN (2,3,4)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
having COUNT(1)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select propertyFeatures.PropertyId     from (
SELECT count(propertyFeatures.PropertyId),   propertyFeatures.PropertyId    
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] IN (1,2)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
having COUNT(1)>1) a

select propertyFeatures.PropertyId     from
SELECT count(propertyFeatures.PropertyId),   propertyFeatures.PropertyId    
FROM PropertyFeatures propertyFeatures INNER JOIN Feature feature ON feature.id = propertyFeatures.FeatureId
WHERE propertyFeatures.[FeatureId] IN (2,3,4)
GROUP BY propertyFeatures.PropertyId
having COUNT(1)>1) a
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query asks for those propertyID for which FeatureID is 1 or 2, what u want is to get those ID for which FeatureID is 1 AND 2. In order to do that change your query to:

```
SELECT pf.PropertyId
FROM PropertyFeatures pf INNER JOIN Feature f ON f.id=pf.FeatureID
WHERE pf.FeatureId in (1,2)
GROUP BY pf.PropertyId
HAVING COUNT(pf.PropertyId)=2
```